# Converting RDD[Long, String, Long] to sql.DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have RDD[Long, String, Long] and i want to convert it to sql.DataFrame in order to execute spark sql on the data.

Any insights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have RDD like:

```
val rdd = Seq((1,"abc",200),(2,"abc",200))
```

toDF can be used to convert rdd to [DataFrame](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html):

```
val rdd = Seq((1,"abc",200),(2,"abc",200)).toDF
```

Note - if you are not in the spark-shell and writing class/object, you need to include below line before the conversion.

```
import spark.implicits._
```

Here spark is an instance of [SparkSession](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession.html).
Hope this helps.